# What is the meaning of “donner sa langue aux chats”?

Tags: expressions, sens, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques

I've seen *Une vie de chat*, and there is a moment when the thief talks to the girl, and asks her name, and she doesn't reply, and then the thief asks "*Tu ne veux pas me parler, t'as donné ta langue aux chats?*".

My dictionary gives a translation "refuse to guess / refuse to solve a puzzle", but it doesn't really suit the context. What is the intended meaning here?

Also, the dictionary mentions that it is also possible to say "*donner (ou jeter) sa langue aux chiens*". Is it possible and if yes, does it have the same meaning?

Comment: I'd say "What's the matter, cat got your tongue?"

Comment: A very funny thing happened here. This phrase was used not idiomatically, but almost in its direct meaning. But translated into English, it has happened to take exactly the form of another idiom, this time an English one, the one that you've cited. Now, given almost total European bilinguism, I can only guess whether the person who has written this dialogue has foreseen this translation trick (or was he even counting on it?).

Comment: Olga's comment refers to JL344's one, for those blindly searching for said idiom.

Comment: Pour dire ça, de nos jours, on dirait plutôt "t'as perdu ta langue" ?.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I gather there's a pun.
"Je donne ma langue au(x) chat(s)" as your dictionary says a colloquial phrase meaning "I give up guessing, just tell me".  But in the context you describe I expect it is not used in the figurative way but strictly means the girl has given her tongue to the cat, therefore she's lost it and can't talk.

"Donner sa langue au(x) chien(s)" has the same meaning and I don't think it is really used nowadays.
See French dictionary [here](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/langue) for meaning
and [here](http://bernardlarquier.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/chansons-a-devinettes/) for a possible origin.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I hoped there to be some kind of jeu de mots, and it's just a joke. Well, at least the dictionary is correct =) So, "donner sa langue aux chats" is still in use, but not "donner sa langue aux chiens"?

Comment: @Olga: Personnellement je n'emploie pas « je donne ma langue aux chiens » et ne l'entends pas dire en France autour de moi (mais la France n'est pas le seul pays francophone !).

Comment: Merci =) Est-ce que c'est la mem chose pour "... aux chats"?

Comment: @Olga: Donner sa langue au chat est une expression familière très courante en français de France.

Comment: @Laure au Canada, c'est la même chose, je n'ai jamais entendu "donner sa langue aux chiens", mais "donner sa langue aux chats" est courant.

Comment: I would say that in the context of the question, "donner sa langue au chat" is probably not used correctly. "Tu as perdu ta langue ?" seems more appropriate to me, and less confusing with the expression having a quite different meaning...

Comment: Sadly, hyperlinks die on the world wide web. [Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20140122085840/https://bernardlarquier.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/chansons-a-devinettes/) is an archived version of the etymology: > Il y a bien longtemps on organisé des duels « d’énigmes » qui opposaient les anciens rois d’Egypte à ceux de Babylone. Le vaincu devait payer un lourd tribut au vainqueur, mais aussi, il devait donner sa langue aux chiens, d’où l’expression « donner sa langue au chiens ou… aux chats »

Answer (score 2):

*« Jeter sa langue au chien »* est une très ancienne expression puis elle a évolué et s'est transformée en *« Donner sa langue au chat »* pour que ce soit moins barbare.